# Javascript or comparison arrays not working?

Tags: javascript

```
var answers = ["hello", "my name is", "how are you?", "what is your name?", "how much does         it cost?"];

var answers2 = ["hi", "my name is", "are you well?", "what's your name?", "how much is     it?"];

$("#submmit").click(function() {
    var totalYes=0;
    function checkAnswers() {
    for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
        var userAnswer = document.getElementById("b"+i).value;
        if(userAnswer===(answers[i] || answers2[i])) {
            totalYes++;
            $("#correcto").show();
        } else {
            $("#incorrecto").show();
        }
    }
    }
    checkAnswers();
});
```

The program works when I type in the correct answer from the answers array, but not from answers2. When I type in the answer from answers2, it shows as "incorrect". Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't check the `answers2` array because

```
(answers[i] || answers2[i])
```

this expression evaluates `answers[i]` first, and that is Truthy (non empty string), so that is returned. Since `||` short circuits, the `answers2[i]` is never evaluated at all.

Correct way to check this would be to use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like this

```
if (answers.indexOf(userAnswer) !== -1 || answers2.indexOf(userAnswer) !== -1) {
    totalYes++;
    $("#correcto").show();
} else {
    $("#incorrecto").show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. I hope this solves your problem

```
if(userAnswer == answers[i] || userAnswer == answers2[i])
```

try replacing this line.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVa89/1/)